# Rate limit new connections in IPTables instead of Nginx or HAProxy?

Tags: nginx, iptables, firewall, haproxy

I would like to use some form of rate-limiting both 1) new TCP connections and 2) requests over an existing connection to HTTP(S). I will probably handle #2 with nginx or HAProxy (because I have more information about the user's history there).

However, I would like to prevent DoS (not DDos) with IPtables and save HAProxy or Nginx some load dealing with new TCP connections. It seems IPTables would be best suited to this job.

```
# Allow unlimited 80 traffic from our own network (duplicate this line for other local subnets)
# 192.168.16.0 - 192.168.16.255
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT

# Simple, single-IP DoS protection 
# Per-minute: Allow up to 200 new connections (packets) from an IP before rate-limiting to 50 packets is applied
# This could need to be an ISP, company, or college where 200 clients all connected from a single IP gateway
# in 1 minute and started using your service. After that first minute 50 more can join every minute.
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 50/minute --limit-burst 200 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 50/minute --limit-burst 200 -j ACCEPT
```

Is this a good idea, or should I just do both types of rate limiting (new/established) at the nginx or HAproxy level?

(Note: I don't have access to an actual hardware firewall which is designed to handle this)

Comment: please consider masses surfing through proxies, which might get cut of with rate limiting. I.e. big corporations, or an isp giving ipv6 to customers and tunneling all ipv4 traffic through a single proxy. I strongly recommend to not rate limit at all.

Comment: @edlerd I will. It seems like a better approach to all this would be decreasing the timeout, using something like a cookie (so you didn't have to wait for an ACK), or building up ISP reputation somehow so you could learn who was a legitimate gateway and who was just wasting resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would rate limit only for specific TCP packets (syn flood, scans of various types, etc) with iptables and use nginx to rate limit [HTTP requests per time interval](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) behind this.

Keep in mind that browsers open multiple TCP connections for a single actual user so rate limiting to 50 connections per minute once the burst is reached is *dramatically* low and may cause trouble for people behind proxies.

Furthermore, nothing proves that a remote client establishing a TCP connection will send a request if you filter only on the NEW state in iptables rules. That means anyone that has access to an infrastructure not honoring ingress/egress filtering best practices can SYN flood your service with spoofed IPs thus degrading the service for specific targets, for instance mobile phone APs of famous companies.

Comment: 1) Why rate limit in nginx instead of IPTables? Isn't the same issue with possibly hundreds of users connecting via a proxy or ISP still the same? 2) Limiting SYN connections does see better than NEW (`-A INPUT -p tcp --syn` right?). However, isn't that the same problem with blocking legitimate traffic? I read something about changing the SYN timeout and "syn-cookies" so I'm going to look into them now. As it is, it doesn't seem possible to rate-limit since a Bot or legitimate ISP could both send 10,000 new syn packets. hrm...

Comment: @Xeoncross Most of this is already answered in my post but I can try to find other words. 1) Nginx limit HTTP requests, iptables limit TCP packets : this is a 3 OSI layers difference i.e. in nginx you rate limit on your application layer (HTTP) while with iptables your rate limit on the transport layer (TCP). Browsers open multiple TCP connections for a single real user but it doesn't necessarily translate in an application load proportionnal to that amount of connection established. It's up to you to decide the rate limiting burst and mean depending on the popularity and expected trafic.

Comment: @Xeoncross Limiting on the application side allows to have a better user experience because you are not refusing or queueing TCP connections but queueing HTTP requests. This means you can smoothly deliver a custom page telling your visitors that the site is overloaded for the moment instead of refusing raw TCP connections and letting your visitors confused. 2) The hard part is to shape this rate limiting to expected traffic, particularly on popular websites. What's done most of the time in this case is getting rate limiting thresholds to kick in only on obviously illegitimate packet rates.

Comment: @Xeoncross It's very unlikely that a legitimate IP will send you for instance 10.000 SYNs in a second. What I observed most of the time on production plateforms under high traffic is a global ratio of ~ 20 between TCP connections in ESTABLISHED state and TCP connections in SYN_RECV state server-side.